# how to set up the appropriate model setting and layers for high intra-class variation

Tags: caffe, conv-neural-network

all experts

I am new in CNN and Caffe. I have a task in classification between 2 classes. The data set that I have collected is very small about 50 for class A and 50 for class B (I know that it is very very small). It is a human images.
I took the BVLC model and made a change such as Batch size for testing and training and also the maximum iteration. I try with many various setup, but the model doesn't work. 
Any idea about how to come up with appropriate model or setting or other solutions ?

remark** I once randomly made a change to the BVLC model setup and it worked, but i lost the set up file.

For the **train.prototxt** and **Solve.prototxt**, I get it from this guy [Adil Moujahid](https://github.com/adilmoujahid/deeplearning-cats-dogs-tutorial/tree/master/caffe_models/caffe_model_1)

I did try training batch size as 32,64,128,256 and testing for 5,20,30 but failed

For the data set, it is images of normal women and beautiful women and i will classify it, but Stackoverflow does not allowed me to add more than 2 links

I wonder that is there any formula , equation or steps that I can come up with and choose the right model setting.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is vague. You need to be more specific and provide more information. What is the network you're using? Provide your ```train.prototxt``` and ```solver.prototxt``` file. You should also provide a screen shot of your training output on the terminal.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I have added a source of my train and text.prototxt

Answer (score 0):

What is your meaning in "doesn't work"? Loss stays too high? Training is converged, but accuracy is low?  Andrew Ng has an excellent session on "debugging" CNNs - Nuts and Bolts of Building Applications using Deep Learning ([NIPS slides](https://nips.cc/Conferences/2016/Schedule?showEvent=6203), [summary](https://medium.com/@aniketvartak/nuts-and-bolts-of-applying-deep-learning-summary-84b8a8e873d5), [additional summary](https://kevinzakka.github.io/2016/09/26/applying-deep-learning/)).

My humble guess is that your network has an overfitting problem - it learns the specific examples and can't generalize - so increasing the train dataset / regularization / data augmentation can help.